# How to list/ get events from a shared (non-primary) calendar using google api php client library for service account?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the google-api-php-client-0.6.1 (API v3) to list/ get events from a shared (non-primary) calendar for service account? I am able to make the request via the API with these settings:

```
client id: xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
service account name: xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
my google account is: yyy@gmail.com
```

and what i am trying to do is to insert/list/get events from calendar in yyy@gmail.com.

when i do the following, it works:

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');
```

however, when i do the following, it doesn't work:

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('yyy@gmail.com');
```

and i get an error "invalid json in service response", can anyone give offer any assistance?

---

(also posted my question in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-php-client/WBjrQRQTb8Y%29))

Comment: hi, can someone please help for the above question?

Answer (score 1):

An email address can have a lot of calendars associated with it.  `listEvents()` accepts one of those calendar ids as a parameter.

It can be found if you go to the calendar's settings, toward the bottom you will see "Calendar Address" with something like "(Calendar ID: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@group.calendar.google.com)."

Comment: thanks allicarn, i tried to put the calendar id as a parameter: $service->events->insert(CALENDAR_ID, $event); but still shows error, can you or anyone help on this issue? thanks in advance..

Comment: I am not sure, it appears that what you have matches the documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples > PHP).  I would try it with and without the "@group.calendar.google.com".